# This does not make $sel = 1 yet it should, why doesn't it?

Tags: php, if-statement, web

This does not make $sel = 1 yet it should, why doesn't it?

```
            $countryVar = 'SouthAfrica';
    $day = 'South Africa';
    $cutCountry = str_replace(" ", "", $day);
    if($cutCountry == $CountryVar) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $cutCountry . '" selected>' . $row["Country"] . '</option>';
        $sel = 1;
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $cutCountry . '">' . $row["Country"] . '</option>';
    }
if($sel == 0) {
    echo '<option value="na" selected>- Please Select Country -</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the variable name on line 4:

```
$countryVar != $CountryVar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is spelling mistake , please change like below.

Replace `if($cutCountry == $CountryVar) {`

To `if($cutCountry == $countryVar) {`

Spelling mistake in `$countryVar`.